# Show Tags in Enterprise-Architect Diagram via Add-In

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise-architect

I am using the following code to generate a diagram in Enterprise-Architect (Add-In with C#):

```
using EA;
...
public int AddDiagram(string name)
    {
        Package treeSelectedPackage = repository.GetTreeSelectedPackage();
        Diagram dgr = treeSelectedPackage.Diagrams.AddNew(name, "Extended::Requirements");
        dgr.Update();
        treeSelectedPackage.Diagrams.Refresh();
        treeSelectedPackage.Update();
        return dgr.DiagramID;
    }
```

repository is an `EA.Repository`-Object.

I am able to add elements to the diagram, but I need to turn on the display of tags/tagged values in the diagram. In Enterprise-Architect you enable it by:

right click in diagram -> Properties... -> Tab 'Elements' -> Show Compartments: Check 'Tags'

What do I have to add to the method above to enable this for a new diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Diagram` class, some of the diagram's properties are available for setting (eg `ShowPackageContents`), while others are not. The element tag property is one of the latter.

However, there are two additional attributes which encapsulate the other properties, `StyleEx` and `ExtendedStyle`, which correspond to the `t_diagram` table's `StyleEx` and `PDATA` columns, respectively. Both of these are read/write, but their contents are undocumented so there is no guarantee that the layout won't change from one version of EA to the next (although in practice you're safe since EA is typically very good at maintaining backward compatibility).

Each is on the form `keyword=value;`, where the value in most cases is 1 or 0 for true/false. The element tag property is in `ExtendedStyle` and is called `ShowTags`.

EA sets all these properties when the diagram is created, but you only want to change one. So what you need to do is create the diagram including the `Update()` call, do a search of `ExtendedStyle`, replacing `ShowTags=0;` with `ShowTags=1;`, and then call `Update()` again.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I added the two lines dgr.ExtendedStyle = "ShowTags=1;";
            dgr.Update();

Comment: It would be safer (as Uffe suggested) to search ExtendedStyle for "ShowTags=0;" and if found replace it with "ShowTags=1;" else search for "ShowTags=1;" and if found do nothing else append "ShowTags=1;" to the end of ExtendedStyle. This would prevent you from overwriting any other style settings.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I checked ExtendedStyle but it appeared empty ("") so i didn't see any necessity to search or append in it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to update the database, "ShowTags=0;" in t_diagram table, use repository.SQLQuery method

Comment: What statement do I have to use? I tried repository.SQLQuery("UPDATE t_diagram SET ShowTags='1';"); but it gives me an error